# Sql query to select products with not unique position of image in gallery

Tags: sql

For example I have a table

[image]

entity_id is for product id. position is for product gallery image position(it needs to show product images in certain order on frontend).

So, every product has a couple of images and those images have their positions in gallery.

Is it possible to find products where their images have not unique positions? For example this product with entity_id 9916 has two images with repeating position 1 and 7:

[image]

I can find all records that have more than 1 image with position 1 with this sql query:

```
SELECT entity_id 
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
WHERE store_id = 1 
AND `position` = 1
GROUP BY entity_id 
HAVING COUNT(entity_id) > 1
```

but how to find all products with repeating positions, but not necessarily 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity_id FROM (
  SELECT entity_id, position  FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
  WHERE store_id = 1     
  GROUP BY entity_id, position
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) r;
```

In subquery you count per entity and position

In main query you keep only entity

Comment: This produces ```SQL Error [1055] [42000]: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by```

Comment: I found, that in subquery in select you need to change * to entity_id, position and this will work.

Comment: Yes I wrote it too qucikly, I cupdate my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add position into your GROUP BY and SELECT clauses, and remove it from your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT entity_id, position
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value 
WHERE store_id = 1     
GROUP BY entity_id, position
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```